# File chooser support in phonegap for ios and Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, cordova

I'm building a cross platform application using Apache Cordova for ios and android. I need a "File chooser" support in my app to upload files (document files not images) to server from the mobile. Is there an alternative for the input element type='file' that supports older versions as well?

Note: The location of the file which is to be uploaded to the server is unknown. User needs to browse the phone and upload documents.

Comment: It's interesting how something like this isn't supported in the official plugins. Did you end up using a separate plugin per platform, out of curiosity?

Answer (score 6):

You have some plugins for android

https://github.com/MaginSoft/MFileChooser

https://github.com/cdibened/filechooser

https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser

And one plugins for iOS

https://github.com/jcesarmobile/FilePicker-Phonegap-iOS-Plugin